# Wrong Hyperref reference due to part

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing

Some of the references in my PDF are correct in their numbering, but the hyperref leads to somewhere else.

I tried the solution suggested here

[part with setcounter -- destination with the same identifier](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22208/part-with-setcounter-destination-with-the-same-identifier)

But redefining the command didn't work.

The numberingwithin solution did work, meaning it is the problem of losing track of references due to the fact the document arranges in parts.

But I don't want this solution. It makes the numbering include part, more cumbersome. 
`\numberwithin{section}{part}`

I tried to set the part to part* and it didn't work either.

I get these errors

```
pdfTeX warning (ext4): destination with the same identifier (name{defn.3}) has 
been already used, duplicate ignored
<to be read again> 
                   \relax 
l.2100 \begin{defn}[3-Product-Case]
```

Any suggestions or ideas?

Specifically, maybe I didn't put 
`\renewcommand*{\theHsection}{\thepart.\thesection}`
in the correct place. I put it after `\usepackage{hyperref}`  before `\usepacket{cleverref}`

Comment: Please inlcude a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: I will try to, but not much time. I think there are limited reasons to why this solution might not work, and maybe someone could figure it out. Or maybe refer me to additional info he needs.

Comment: the duplicate destination is a definition: `(name{defn.3})`. It doesn't make much sense to redefine \theHsection then, try to (re)define `\theHdefn` instead.

Comment: you have pages with same number (for example in roman in the front-mater and than with arabic in main mater).

Comment: But isn't it related? because the definition takes its numbering from the section. Or maybe it doesn't know it. Will check it out, thanks!